# Error updating profile

Tags: profile, custom-profile

I am currently experiencing an error when trying to update a profile. Does anyone know how to fix the below error?

> Permission Deploy Change Sets depends on permission(s): Modify All
>   Data

Answer (score 1):

> This error means that somewhere you have provided any related child object higher access than parent object which is now throwing you the error for the parent object permissions.

Comment: This is not a great answer, as it does not appear helpful in the first place, but yes indeed this did help me solve my problem. I had Modify All on Cases and did not have Modify All on Accounts so when I tried to set Modify All on Account, this is what made this error appear. The error is so bad and gives you absolutely no indication as to what is the actual issue.